# How to specify starting position for Kafka consumers when using dynamic group re-balancing?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to start 0.9 or 0.10 Kafka consumers from a specified offset , while still using consumer groups with dynamic re-balancing?

Here is what have found so far:

Case 1: If we use consumer.assign(…)  method to manually assign partitions to consumers - we can do all below actions:

```
consumer.seek(<specificPartition>, <myCustomOffset>); or:
consumer.seekToBeginning(<specificPartition>);
consumer.seekToEnd(<specificPartition>);
```

Basically, we have full control over which position to start the consumer form, BUT it is at the expense of not having the partition re-assignment done dynamically by Kafka

Case 2: If we use consumer.subscribe(…)  method  - Kafka will manage the re-balancing, however, we cannot do any of the three options above … :(
So, we tried the following to “hack” around it - at the consumer start up time, ***before*** entering the poll() loop:

```
// get coordinator from the private field of the consumer:
ConsumerCoordinator coordinator = (ConsumerCoordinator) FieldUtils.readField(consumer, "coordinator", true);
// make sure all partitions are already 
coordinator.ensurePartitionAssignment();
// get the list of partitions assigned to this specific consumer:
Set<TopicPartition> assignedTopicPartitions = consumer.assignment()
// now we can go ahead and do the same three actions (seek(), sequined() or seekToBeginning()) on those partitions only for this consumer as above.
for (TopicPartition assignedPartition: assignedTopicPartitions) {
     consumer.seek(<assignedPartition>, <myCustomOffset>) // or whatever
...
}
// now start the poll() loop:
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(pollIntervalMs);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         // processMessage(record.value(), record.offset());
    }
}
```

This feels too hack-y for my taste, and, also, I am not sure if this logic will hold during the actual re-balancing , when, say, new consumers are added to the group.

Could somebody validate this approach or suggest a better way to accomplish what we need ?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ConsumerCoordinator` you can just do an initial `poll()` (and do not process anything) to get partitions assigned. Afterwards, use `seek()` and start you poll-loop as shown in your code.

Comment: thanks for the idea! However, AFAIK, poll() will retrieve events regardless of whether I actually iterate over them or not - and Kafka will save the offsets at some point.... So, unless I also add explicit offset commits and disable auto commits by Kafka - I might loose the events from the first poll() if, for example, I do seekToEnd() ... Is this what you are suggesting - adding the manual offset commits? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to have more control, manual commits would work. However, I am not sure why you would "loose" data. As long as retention time is large enough, you can always seek back -- and if you want to seekToEnd() you want to skip over the data anyway. Or do I miss something? Keep in mind, that committed offsets must not increase necessarily. For example, if you process data and commit offset 10, seek back to offset 5, you can still commit 5 afterwards. The committed offset only determines where you want to proceed in case of shutdown/failure by default (ie, without the need to manually seek)

Comment: You are correct -sorry, I did not clarify my use case: with seekToEnd() or seekToBeginning() or seek() - no problem with not processing events from the first poll(). The use case I had in mind was when for *some* partitions I would want to do RESTART from the whatever offset they finished at, and for some - do a custom offset restart. I think in this case the only approach to not skip processing any messages in those partitions/consumers that use normal RESTART option is to commit offsets explicitly.  Thanks again for the quick answer!